# DowithIf() for looing over the data in Excel/VB is not running

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script in Excel/VB and want to run it. Once I run it, I got: `Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)`.

What has to be corrected? My code is only summing up the pair of duplicates: what to add to sum over the Multiple Duplicate Values?

```
Sub DowithIf()
    rw = 2
    cl = 4
    erw = 1655

    Do While rw < erw
        Cells(rw, cl).Select
        Cells(rw - 1, cl).Select
        Cells(rw, cl + 1).Select
        Cells(rw, cl + 1).HorizontalAligment = xlCenter

        If Cells(rw, cl) = Cells(rw - 1, cl) Then
            Cells(rw + 1, cl) = Cells(rw, cl - 1) + Cells(rw - 1, cl - 1)
            Cells(rw, cl + 1) = Interior.Color = 13431551
        ElseIf Cells(rw, cl) = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
End Sube
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
End Sube
```

with the statement:

```
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but there were no e in my script in the vb, but thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @sawsaw. Look at the last line.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have
`Cells(rw, cl + 1) = Interior.Color = 13431551`

Replace it with
`Cells(rw, cl + 1).Interior.Color = 13431551`

And it should work

Comment: thanks but now it gives Error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error!